# After updating OSx Big Mister Can't start mini kube

Tags: minikube, scp, macos-big-sur

It works fine before the update.

After updating Big Boss I can't start mini-kube.

```
minikube minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.19.2     

Exiting due to K8S_INSTALL_FAILED: updating control plane: copy: copy: sudo test -d /var/tmp/minikube && sudo scp -t /var/tmp/minikube: Process exited with status 1
output: �scp: /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml.new: Read-only file system
scp: protocol error: expected control record
```

Maybe I need to add some settings?

Answer (score 0):

Big Sur is a bit unstable. I use a MBA 2015 and couldn't upgrade to Big Sur. I am using Catalina right now. Because of 128GB space that I have is not enough to free up 42GB of free space.
But at least I decided to stay in Catalina is better because there are lots of comments about bugs and problems in Big Sur. And if I would upgrade, my computer may be slower because it is 5 years old.
Install it if there is a snapshot version or a newer version compatible with Big Sur. If there isn't, I'm afraid you have to wait for a BigBoss compatible version.